# How to add values to a list in java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I am trying to create a method called

```
public SensorList<Sensor> getSensorList(String sensorType)
```

which returns a `SensorList` that contains all the sensor objects of a specific type, like temperature or humidity.

If `sensorType = “temperature”`, then the `getSensorList` should return a `SensorList` that contains all temperature objects from the measurements list.

If `sensorType = “humidity”`, then the `getSensorList` should return a `SensorList` that contains all humidity objects from the measurements list.

We ignore other types of sensors.

Note: I already made a method in class `Sensor` called add which add to a list. Also class `Sensor` has one attribute `ArrayList<T>` and two constructors one default to declare the the arrayList and the other to initialize the attribute list to the parameter `List<T>`

```
public SensorList<Sensor> getSensorList(String sensorType) {

    if (sensorType.equalsIgnoreCase("sensor")) {        
        return new SensorList<Sensor>();
    } else if (sensorType.equalsIgnoreCase("temperature")) {
        return new SensorList<Temperature>();
    } else if (sensorType.equalsIgnoreCase("humidity")) {
        return new SensorList<Humidity>();
    }

}
```

This is my code but it keeps giving me errors so how can I solve this problem?

Can I get any suggestions on how to write the method in the correct way?

Comment: "*but it keeps giving me errors*" - well, what errors?

Comment: This is because you are returning an ilegal object in you method you declared to return SensorList<Sensor> but i see that you return SensorList<Temperature>() and SensorList<Humidity>() this is not the same list that you declared in your method

Comment: Is Temperature and Humidity a subclass of Sensor? Because your method want a SensorList with objects of type Sensor as return value.

Comment: public SensorList<?> getSensorList(String sensorType)

Comment: Apart from the wrong return type: It is also missing a return statement if none of the if statements evaluate to true!

Comment: @M.Sc Yes they are subclasses of Sensor

Comment: @TAMIMSAMIOALHUSSAIN Please edit your Question with clarifications rather than post as comments. Explain the nature of Temperature and Humidity in the Question.

Comment: Can you just put your Sensor class code to help you solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

The "error" are probably because you haven't declared the type `Sensor`.

I suspect you *actually* want a type that *is* a Sensor:

```
public <T extends Sensor> SensorList<T> getSensorList(String sensorType) {
    ...
```

but your code adds no value, since the type returned is always unsafe and the compiler can not infer the type from the `sensorType` parameter.

I don't know what your intention is, but I suggest deleting this method entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Are `Temperature` and `Humidity` subclasses of `Sensor`? Your method is supposed to return a `SensorList` of `Sensor` objects but its implementation can return a `SensorList` of `Temperature` or `Humidity` objects.

Make sure both `Temperature` and `Humidity` classes extend from `Sensor` or make the return type of the `getSensorList` method more generic (**not recommended!**) such as `SensorList<Object>`.

Also your method does not return any result when no if statement is matched.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your method generic:

```
public <T> SensorList<T> getSensorList(Class<T> sensorClass) {
    return new SensorList<T>();
}
```

and call the method like this:

```
getSensorList(Humidity.class);
```

If *Humidity* and *Temperature* classes are sub-classes of *Sensor*, then you can narrow down the type in method signature to:

```
public <T extends Sensor> SensorList<T> getSensorList(Class<T> sensorClass)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
ArrayList[Sensor] measurementslist;
```

You can check the type of each element in the list and add it if it matches what you want:

```
ArrayList[Sensor] myResultList = new ArrayList[Sensor]();
for (Iterator<Sensor> i = measurementslist.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
  Sensor item = i.next();
  if (Temperature.isInstance( item )) {
    myResultList.add(item);
  }
}
```